# bind onClick function in React.CreateClass

Tags: reactjs

//Here is my Code All Working but when i try to add onClick function with it than i get error that this.getComponent is not a function

```
var NavMenu = React.createClass({
        getComponent: function(index) {
            console.log("Bingo");
        },
        render: function()
        {
            if (this.props.data.length != 0)
            {   

                return (
                    <div className="dropdown pad_right">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.props.name}
                        <span className={this.props.icon}></span></button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                          {this.props.data.map(function(name){
                                if(name.isHeader) {
                                   return  <li onClick={this.getComponent.bind(this, 1)}><a>{name.key}</a></li>;
                                }else {
                                    return <li className="dropdown-header">{name.key}</li> 
                                }
                          })}
                        </ul>
                  </div>
                );
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind your function when using React.createClass, react handles it automatically. If you want to pass your own parameter to the function, you can do something like this:

```
<li onClick={(event) => this.getComponent(1)}>
  <a>{name.key}</a>
</li>
```

Also, since you're calling this function inside a loop, this error might be caused because the scope of your class is lost, you can try doing so:

```
{this.props.data.map((name) => {
  if(name.isHeader) {
    return  <li onClick={(event) => this.getComponent(1)}><a>{name.key}</a></li>;
  }else {
    return <li className="dropdown-header">{name.key}</li> 
  }
})}
```

The arrow function, `(name) => ...` will bind the function scope to the class scope